# Custom Component TImage events causing error "Does not exist"

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, vcl

I have a custom component witht the following events

```
 private
    { Private declarations }
    ...
    fOnImageClick: TNotifyEvent;
    fOnImageMouseUp: TMouseEvent;
    fOnImageMouseDown: TMouseEvent;
    fOnImageMouseMove:  TMouseMoveEvent;
    fOnImageMouseEnter: TNotifyEvent;
    fOnImageMouseLeave: TNotifyEvent;
    fOnImageSelect: TNotifyEvent;
    fOnImageDblClick: TNotifyEvent;
  protected
    ...
  public
    { Public declarations }
     ...
  published
     ...
     property OnImageClick: TNotifyEvent read  fOnImageClick write  fOnImageClick;
     property OnImageSelect: TNotifyEvent read  fOnImageSelect write  fOnImageSelect;
     property OnImageDblClick: TNotifyEvent read  fOnImageDblClick write  fOnImageDblClick;
     property OnImageMouseDown: TMouseEvent read  fOnImageMouseDown write  fOnImageMouseDown;
     property OnImageMouseUp: TMouseEvent read  fOnImageMouseUp write  fOnImageMouseUp;
     property OnImageMouseMove:  TMouseMoveEvent read  fOnImageMouseMove write  fOnImageMouseMove;
     property OnImageMouseLeave: TNotifyEvent read  fOnImageMouseLeave write  fOnImageMouseLeave;
     property OnImageMouseEnter: TNotifyEvent read  fOnImageMouseEnter write  fOnImageMouseEnter;
  end;
```

I assign them to a TImage whose parent is TPanel whos parent is TScrollBox

```
 img:= TImage.Create(ThumbPnl);
 img.Parent:= ThumbPnl;
 img.Tag:= I;
 img.Align:= alClient;
 img.Stretch:= true;
 img.OnClick:= fOnImageClick;
 img.OnDblClick:= fOnImageDblClick;
 img.OnMouseEnter:= fOnImageMouseEnter;
 img.OnMouseLeave:= fOnImageMouseLeave;
 img.OnMouseDown:= fOnImageMouseDown;
 img.OnMouseUp:= fOnImageMouseUp;
 img.OnMouseMove:= fOnImageMouseMove;
```

The component compiles and bulds just fine. The application with this component also compiles and runs jus fine. If I assign an OnClick event, it works. All other events, if I assign them and try to run the app, i get an error saying the event doesn't exist

Anyone know why that is?

Comment: Please give the exact error message. Don't describe error messages. Quote them. Verbatim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## What is an event

The event in Delphi is a method pointer. A method pointer is basically two pointers, one points to the method you assign to the event, and the other points to the live instance (object) you assign.

## What I assume you're expecting

I think you expect the event in your inner object follows the events assigned to your outer object, and that will not happen automatically.

When you assign it, you're doing pointer assignments. So to take an example, your line

```
img.OnDblClick:= fOnImageDblClick;
```

Performs a pointer assignment with the value `fOnImageDblClick` have at the time. If it is `nil`, `img.OnDblClick` will be `nil` from now. If it *points* to `Form1.MyComponentImageClick` at the time, `img.OnDblClick` will point to the same method on the same object from now, **but**, if you later change where fOnImageDblClick points, the imgOnDblClick will not follow... it will remains pointing to the same *old* address. If you want it to change, you have to make that change by code also.

If you want that to happen, you can do that in a event setter in the outer class.

First, declare your events like this:

```
published
  ...
  property OnImageDblClick: TNotifyEvent read  fOnImageDblClick write  SetOnImageDblClick; 

...
procedure TMyClass.SetOnImageDblClick(Value: TNotifyEvent);
begin
  FOnImageDblClick := Value;
  //pass the new value to the inner object.
  if Assigned(Img) then
    Img.OnDblClick := Value;
end;
```

If your `Img` inner object exists all the time, you don't need the `FOnImageDblClick` variable, you can write also a getter for the property and take the value directly from the inner object, like this:

```
function TMyClass.GetOnImageDblClick: TNotifyEvent;
begin
  Result := Img.OnDblClick;
end;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that snipplet of code where img is created and all the events are assigned to it, is in a loop in a protected method (UpdateViewer) of the component. There can be n number of them.  This is a imageviewer component. Therefore, i wouldn't have access to it in the setter method - would I? Is there another way?

Comment: I moved the img variable into from where it was locally into the global position (private section) of the component - Works great now!

Answer (score 6):

You are making a fairly common mistake for new component creators.  You are breaking this rule:

> Component users write event handlers, component writers "fire" events

In your case what you are doing is assigning events when you as the component developer shouldn't be doing that.  It's up to the component user to assign code to occur in the `OnClick`, `OnDblClick`, etc. events.

It's enough for you to declare the events as Published and as TNotifyEvent types.

```
property OnSomeEvent: TNotifyEvent read FOnSomeEvent write FOnSomeEvent;
```

That's all you need to do to create the events.  Your job is to "fire" them; that is, make them happen.

That is done in your component at the appropriate moment.  Usually, what you'll do is create a method DoXXXXX where XXXXX is the thing that is happening.  So you'd create

```
procedure TMyImage.DoSomeEvent;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnSomeEvent) then FOnSomeEvent(Self);
end;
```

Then, within your code, when the event should be fired, you simply call `DoSomeEvent`.

Now, if you want to *enhance* the functionality of the default events, then you need to override the method that fires the event.

I hate to do it, but my classic component TSmiley illustrates this simply and clearly:

http://tsmiley.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tsmiley/

Take a look at that example and you should see how to create events.

Comment: +1 for "I hate to do it" and for the classic TSmiley component. :p

Comment: The question describes a different scenario. The code in the Q wants for the users events to fire when the image events fire. So the image events need to be set to handlers defined in the component. And they in turn do the `if Assigned(FOnSomeEvent) then FOnSomeEvent(Sender);` dance.